# RecyclerView: cannot maintain consistent item view on scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I display the recycler view in grid view. The recycler view adapter has cardview as the model view in which i have an imageview. Inside `onBindViewHolder` of my adapter I load an image from glide using Firebase Storage Reference.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Glide.with(context).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storagereference.get(position)).centercrop().into(viewholder.imageview);
}
```

Where storagereference is an ArrayList of StorageReference class of Firebase. The problem is when the number of views in recycler view is more than 11 i.e. 12 cards (I'm showing them in a gridview of span 2) and when I scroll the last two items load up the image whose reference is stored in `storagereference.get(0)` and `storagereference.get(1)` respectively. And when i scroll back up the images in the firsr two items change to something else, they either become same or from the `storagereference.get(11)` or `storagereference.get(10)`.

I dont know why it is happening (but I guess its because of recycling of items) although i have .load(storagereference(position)) in my onBindViewHolder() method so it must return the storage reference of the position required(0 for the first item and so on) but somehow it changes.

Please, anyone explain the cause and remedy for this.
Thanks

Comment: instead of this storagereference.get(position) use storagereference.get(getAdapterPosition()) and also check if there is any value or not before loading

Comment: A little snippet would help a lot! Thanks! @ankit aman

Comment: cool, mark this answer as accepted by upvoting

Answer (score 0):

instead of this **storagereference.get(position)** **use** **storagereference.get(getAdapterPosition())** and also check if there is any value or not before loading